# Devnagari Font doesn't display properly in Crystal Report

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, report, hindi

I am using Crystal Report 13.0.24 with Visual Studio 2017 to create reports by fetching data from database. I needed to create section is Hindi using Kruti Dev 010 font. Everything is fine but some half characters of Hindi is causing strange display issue. But, it works fine in MS Word or other applications. Here is the sample image of CR Report:
[Crystal Report Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKJnI.png)

Issue with the words **प्रमाणित** and **विशिष्टता** has a pattern. In Kruti Dev, both **ण** and **श** are half-characters in default. Please suggest some hack or fix.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send this issue to SAP technical team this is happen because of display engine.
http://rajbhasha.net/drupal514/Unicodekrutidev+converter open this website and copy your text and paste adove box and click on "unicode to Kruti dev" and paste result and try again

https://www.unicode.org/faq/indic.html this page has description about this see Question no
16

However, I cannot find the "half forms" of Devanagari letters (or any other Indic script) in the Unicode code charts. These characters are needed to form words such as "patni".

Comment: Try not to frame any part of your answer as a question. It's better to just clarify that there may still be some things missing from your solution. If you have another question, go ahead and post that.